Python iterate every 10 items on button press
I'm struggling trying to iterate every 10 items
So if the list is bellow 10 items it goes perfectly well of curse
If the list is bigger then for every y pressed I want to show the next 10 items like a next page button and also not blowing at the end if I try to get the last 10 items and there's only 5 left
typing y to do next page and any other key previous page
Also note that this is not the real problem. The real one I'm facing is within curses module but I tried to simplify and even that I can't
display = 0
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]

while True:
    # tried this but I need button press
    
    # for i in range(0, len(list), 10):
    #     print(*list[i:i+10])
        

    if len(list) <= 10:
        for i in list:
            print(i)
    else:
        for i in range((display * 10), ((display * 10) + 10) ):
            print(list[i])
            
    np = input()
    if np == 'y':
        display += 1
        # here something that would prevent the next page when there is no more items
    else:
        if display == 0:
            display = 0
        else:
            display -= 1


Use a slice: list[i:i+10] and increment i by 10 each time.

BTW, don't use list as a variable name, it's the name of a built-in type.

I'm sure there are many ways to solve this. One way is iterate over the data printing out the number of entries for the  page size (e.g. 10) and then wait for user key press. Then only exit the loop once the data is exhausted.
I've created the following example which generates data of random length for testing purposes:
import random
start = 1
# Generate content of fixed length for testing
# length = 20
# Generate content of variable length for testing
length = random.randint(5, 40)
data = range(start, start + length)

print(f"Created data {len(data)} long\n")

PAGE_SIZE = 10

def pages_needed(data_len):
    max_page = data_len // PAGE_SIZE
    if data_len % PAGE_SIZE > 0:
        max_page += 1
    return max_page


page_number = 0
data_available = len(data) > 0


while data_available:
    page_start = page_number * PAGE_SIZE
    page_end = min((page_number * PAGE_SIZE) + PAGE_SIZE, len(data))
    total_pages = pages_needed(len(data))
    for entry in data[page_start:page_end]:
        print(f"\t{entry}")
    page_number += 1
    if page_number >= total_pages:
        data_available = False
    else:
        input("Press <return> for the next page of data")


Which gave me the following output:
Created data 17 long

    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    8
    9
    10
Press <return> for the next page of data
    11
    12
    13
    14
    15
    16
    17

